# Get request response contains objectid and versionkey instead of the original data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Route.js:

It contains the implementation of various functions for database operations. Here post is working fine, but whenever a get request is done response contains only objectid and versionkey.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Contact = require('../model/contacts')

//retrieving data
router.get('/contacts',(req,res,next)=>{
    
    Contact.find(function(err,contacts){
        res.json(contacts);
        console.log(Contact.count());
    })
});

//add contact
router.post('/contact',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    let newContact = new Contact({
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        phone: req.body.phone
    });

    newContact.save((err,contact)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            res.json({msg:'Failed to add contact'});
        }
        else
        {
            res.json({msg:'Contact added succefully.'});
        }
    });
});

//deleting contact
router.delete('/contact/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
    Contact.remove({_id: req.params._id},function(err,result){
        if(err)
        {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image: Response for get request]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Can you share your mongo configuration and model contacts? Also, have you check your database to see if documents are inserted correctly?

Comment: Have you used any pre save hooks and not calling next? please check

Comment: seems data are not saved